# Div estilizada com CSS

Tags: html, css3, nav-bar

Preciso fazer uma `div` que tenha a aparência da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer com imagem de background, porém fica mais difícil para posicionar, visto que como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é fazer essa área marcada na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    font-family: 'EurostileLTStd';
    text-align: center;
    color: #16824d;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    z-index: 1030;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.44);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Bacana, e o que tentou? Edite a pergunta e inclua seu código, mesmo que esteja errado.

Comment: Poste seu `html`, `css` e `js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o background: linear-gradient

Você pode fazer assim para gerar diferentes no background:

```
background-color:#4fd8e8;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.4), rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,.4));
```

Referência:http://tableless.com.br/como-usar-gradient-no-css-de-forma-consciente/

Para criar o arrow você pode usar o seletor :before na div em questão e estilizar o borda como desejar:

```
suaDiv:before { 
    content: "";
    border-color: transparent #111;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: -1em;
    top: 0.9em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Através das propriedades border-style, border-width, e border-color você pode mudar como quiser a borda das divs

Se não tiver problemas com Inglês pode acompanhar esse tutorial que vai ensinar a criar um menu exatamente como você precisa: https://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Comment: Na verdade não é nem o gradiente que está me dando problema. Veja a primeira imagem, a parte de cima tem um, digamos, border-radius ao "contrário". Essa é uma nav-bar.

Comment: Coloquei alguns exemplos práticos de como usar o gradient, e o seletor before para manipular a borda

Comment: Esse é o grande problema de responder quando a pergunta não está muito clara ou até ampla. O ideal nesse caso é um voto de fechamento na pergunta até que o autor explique melhor o que quer, para evitar investir tempo e a resposta não servir. Sua boa intenção em ajudar acaba sendo desperdiçada por falta de detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: Forneci alguns links para ajudá-lo acredito que o ultimo é o que mais se aproxima no que ele precisa, mas como ele não especificou exatamente o que quer não quis perder tempo fazendo exemplos práticos

Comment: Obrigado Leo Letto por ter respondido. Acho que os exemplos que vc mandou no link vão me ajudar bastante. Aos esquentadinhos de plantão, quando virem uma pergunta confusa, não precisa responder, se é que isso vai atrapalhar seu precioso tempo.

Comment: @EdinhoRodrigues quando tiver dúvidas tente sempre posta o máximo possível do seu código assim facilita para as pessoas entenderem o que você quer e te responderem com mais precisão, é que o stackoverflow é um pouco objetivo nas repostas, perguntas abertas geralmente são discutidas na área de chats